# How to set glade label without a button event?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade

I'm trying to set a label without a button event.

I want my application to show another message after 2 seconds.

When I run the program, the window just shows me the last message: "bye".

Is the sequence ok? Did I forget anything?

Thanks

[image]

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from time import sleep

class form():

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = Gtk.Builder()
        self.b.add_from_file("color.glade")
        self.ventana_main = self.b.get_object("ventana_main")
        self.label = ""
        self.box = self.b.get_object("box_test") #obj creado en color.glade
        self.box_area = Gtk.Box()
        self.box.add(self.box_area)
        self.b.connect_signals(self)
        self.ventana_main.show_all()

    def label_hi(self, widget):
        self.label = Gtk.Label("Hola")
        self.box_area.add(self.label)
        self.box_area.show_all()

    def label_bye(self, widget):
        self.label.set_markup("Bye")

    def on_ventana_main_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = form()
    f.label_hi(f.ventana_main)
    sleep(2)
    f.label_bye(f.ventana_main)
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do changes before calling `Gtk.main()`, because at that point, your application is not even shown.

If you want a 2 seconds delay, use [GLib.timeout_add_seconds](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add_seconds), and pass the object you want to modify (your label) as the `data` parameter. The `function` parameter you need to pass is the callback that will be called after those 2 seconds. In that callback, you just call [`set_label`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Label.html#Gtk.Label.set_label) (or your `label_bye`) on the label you have passed as the `data` parameter, and you're done.

Another thing is that you should create the label and add it to your widget tree in your constructor, not in your `label_hi` method. `label_hi` and `label_bye` just need to call `set_label` to change the message displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't listen about this library before.
Maybe I was so especific, 
I need change this label in an asynchronous event.
Do you know if I can do anything like that?

Comment: GLib and GObject are the libraries on top of which GTK+ has been developped.

Comment: This is a a new question, so please ask it separately and clarify what you want to achieve.